# Plugin with UIViewController

Tags: ios, cordova, uiviewcontroller, cordova-plugins

Can somebody explain to me the life-cycle of a Cordova iOS plugin?

Particularly, I have a plugin I am trying to develop which contains a `UIView` (and associated `UIViewController`).

How do I obtain the Cordova `UIView` from my extended `CDVPlugin` class, so I can add my plugin as a sub-view to it (is this how it works?).

I would like to temporarily show my `UIView` on top of my Cordova app, then dismiss it, returning to my JS/HTML app.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to present the whole UIViewController (full screen) over the cordova webview, you can do

```
[self.viewController presentViewController:yourViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Examples:

[Camera plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/master/src/ios/CDVCamera.m)

[InAppBrowser plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/src/ios/CDVInAppBrowser.m)

If you want to add just a view over the cordova webview, you can do

```
[self.viewController.view addSubview:yourView];
```

Examples:

[MapKit plugin](https://github.com/imhotep/MapKit/blob/master/src/ios/MapKit.m)

The diference is, that the first method present the whole view controller, full screen, the second method shows a view that can have the size and position you want, if you don't make it have the same size of the device screen the user will see your cordova webview under it

Comment: Awesome - thanks! Do you have any plugins with any examples. What would the difference be between the two?

Comment: Edited with examples and differences

Comment: If you google `presentViewController ` it shows you the Apple documentation page for it, and Apple documentation page can show the information for Objective-C and for Swift. https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-present

Answer (score 2):

Please refer the answer given by @jcesarmobile above

[Plugin with UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31750579/plugin-with-uiviewcontroller/31853288#31853288)

For immature iOS developers like me who were not able to identify how to define yourViewController, follow below code

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController * yourViewController = [storyboard   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"iController"] ;
[self.viewController presentViewController: yourViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Where Main is the storyboard filename and iController is the viewController's storyboardIdentifier defined in the Main.Storyboard file

Please up vote the above answer given by @jcesarmobile