# Show ContainerViewController in Cordova App

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I create small plugin for Cordova in Swift. Only issue I'm facing now is that controller seems to be starting but it is not showing on fullscreen above Cordova application. I think there is some method missing to set view on top of cordova app.

Code:

```
class ContainerViewController: CDVViewController {
var brandID: String!
var authenticationCode:String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
      image: UIImage(named: "backbutton"),
      style: .plain,
      target: self,
      action: #selector(ContainerViewController.backToMainScreen)
  )
  UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
    self.view.alpha = 1.0
  })
}
```

}

Can you guide me what I'm doing wrong and also if possible some chapter in documentation

Comment: how are you showing it right now?

Comment: I found some clue how to do it but this is objective C need Swift version of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31750579/plugin-with-uiviewcontroller?answertab=active#tab-top