# Launching ViewController using objective-c within Cordova project

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, uiviewcontroller, cordova-plugins

Firstly, let me explain the app structure of how it is maintained

I have here two applications

First, a native objective-c based iOS application which is working perfectly, the task of the native application is to launch the camera once the application is launched, capture image and do some OpenGL processing, display the image captured.

This is done by calling ViewController class within my main.m file as shown below

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([ViewController class]));
    }
}
```

This ViewController class has some properties which gets the app up & running & launches a storyboard

Now for the cordova app, I created a plugin and integrated all the native files into the plugin, so once we add the plugin it adds all the resources including source files, resource files, assets, storyboard etc.

When we trigger the plugin within javascript, it will call the native class CustomPlugin which is the starting point of the plugin, below are the header & implementation code of the same

CustomPlugin.h

```
#import <Cordova/CDV.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface CustomPlugin : CDVPlugin

- (void) pluginInitialize;

- (void) process:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;

@end
```

CustomPlugin.h

```
#import "CustomPlugin.h"
#import "ViewController.h"


@interface CustomPlugin()

@end

@implementation CustomPlugin

NSString *_routeChangedCallbackId;
@synthesize viewc;


- (void) pluginInitialize {
    NSLog(@"CustomPlugin:pluginInitialize");

    _routeChangedCallbackId = nil;
}

- (void) process:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:@"test"];
    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
}

@end
```

This implementation currently just sends back the response sample message to the caller

What I want to achieve is to be able to invoke/launch/initialize the ViewController feature as is working in native

Please oblige me for the lengthy question but it was required since I'm too much new to iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Successfully able to resolve my issue of launching a ViewController from Cordova plugin, refer the below post

[Plugin with UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31750579/plugin-with-uiviewcontroller#44580151)

Answer (score 0):

The pluginInitialize method should be called between the CDVPluginResult and commandDelegate methods:

```
  - (void) process:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
    {
        CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:@"test"];

        [self pluginInitialize];

        [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
    }
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html